# OpenCV deployment on windows azure

Tags: opencv, azure

Is it possible to deploy an OpenCV application to windows azure?

Answer (score 0):

Open CV is comes into client application category accessible through user interface and also can be used for backend processing. Windows Azure Cloud services is used for web application so Open CV does not fit in the application model. For backend processing you may think to use cloud service as worker but that need lots of work on your part and defeat the purpose.

For the sake of completeness and possibility, you sure can get a Windows Azure Virtual Machine, along with Windows OS and deploy OpenCV application there. Once ready you can Remote Desktop to the VM and use it. You may pay monthly cost to use the VM but you sure can do it. But I am sure that is not your objective either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'll say its possible to install OpenCV applications to Azure.

Check the following [Deep Learning VM](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.dsvm-deep-learning)

It comes with pre-installed software. Most of the machine learning libraries along with the OpenCV project are pre-installed

You can also use APIs to host your models on the Windows Azure